# SQL Server Grant Remote access to execute Stored Procedures within a given Schema

Tags: sql-server

I am a developer for a hospital which uses software provided by a 3rd party vendor which hosts Sql Server for us. We have a local instance of Sql Server 2012 which has a linked server to their Sql Server instance. Within our instance of Sql Server we can see all of the Views and Tables that have been assigned to us but none of the stored procedures.

However, I have been given a Citrix connection which allows me to access Sql Server on their network. From here, I can create, alter and execute stored procedures in the [CUSTOMER] schema they created for this purposes (we can only execute procs in dbo, but not alter or create).

The vendor is now trying to give me access to execute stored procedures we created in [CUSTOMER] through our linked server. However, it's not working. They say they have given permission to my user as well as the user listed under the Security tab of Linked Server Properties in "Be made using this security context".

Properties for RPC and RPC Out are set to true.

No Sp's show up  under the linked server node (no "programmability" node at all). And when I try to execute my proc like this: [remoteserver.ip.address].[remoteDbInstance].[Customer].[extr_myProc], I get the following error:

```
"Cannot find the object "extr_myProc" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."
```

I suspect there's an issue on their side but our contact at the vendor says they've done everything. Is there something else I should be doing on my side though?

I suspect that there's more than one measure a vendor can take to lock down stored procs over a linked server and all their support staff did was to make sure [CUSTOMER] was executable for our users, but another setting is blocking it specifically for linked servers.

Is there something I can suggest to their support staff to look at for us that can hide stored procs from a user, but only over a linked server?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have already tried this, but if not, maybe it would help if you run 'SELECT CURRENT_USER' against the linked server and see if you get the same result as through Citrix.  Maybe your login to the linked server is not mapping to the user they think it is.

Comment: I had not tried that. When I execute that command on my local sql server it returns "dbo". However, when I execute it through citrix it returns the user name they've assigned me on their system. However, I thought the context of execution would be the Login user that my linked server is running under, not my user name on our system. Does that make sense?

Comment: It must be returning your local username when you run it against your local server.  When I run it against my server, it returns 'dbo' if I am logged in as 'sa', and 'User1' if I am logged in as 'User1'.  I still think it would be helpful to confirm your user context on the linked server, but I don't know the command for that.